# URL rewrite does not work for http to https redirection for clickonce application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, web-services

I am trying to use IIS URL rewrite for  http to https redirection. But after start URL rewrite, clickonce application can not able to install. It is showing an error & creating install.log file. Here are the log file & error message.

Log file:

> URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697208' 
>   Error: An error occurred trying to download 'https://appdev.teamsupport.com/app/appClient.application'

Error message:

> An error occurred trying to download https://apptest.teamsupport.com/app/appClient.application.. 
>   See the setup log file located at 'C\Users\username\AppData\local\Temp\1\VSD69C6Imp \install.log ' for more information.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451496/urldownloadtocachefile-failed-with-hresult-2146697208)? or [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2014/05/14/installation-of-a-clickonce-application-failing-with-an-error)?

Comment: I tried it, but its not working. The problem at URL rewrite. We are using it for http to https redirection. If we stop url rewright ,then clickonce application installing properly.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msiclickonce/2009/12/21/how-to-make-clickonce-work-over-ssl-requiring-client-certificates/

Comment: I tried this one, but issue is still pending