# HRESULT: 2146697208 Unable to download software

Tags: stack, overflow

Unable to dowload software to my Admin account.  However I can download the software to a Local account on the same computer.  Currently running Windows 10  x64.  The install log report an error HRESULT: 2146697208.  Sotware vendor reports it as a Windows problem. I tried to download the software using HTTP and HTTPS URLs, both downloads failed.    Would appreciate any help to correct problem.

Tried effort described above.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/43451496/56778. And, generally, search Stack Overflow for "hresult 2146697208". It looks like the problem has to do either with security settings, or with an invalid URL.