# Clickonce installation is failing to download

Tags: c#, ftp, clickonce

Trying to publishing my project with ClickOnce and getting the follower error when downloading it

URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697211'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'http://fps104/solutions/solutions.application'.

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 10.0.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Release' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read integer value 533320
Setting value '533320 {int}' for property 'DotNetFull_Release'
Reading value 'v4' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\OS Integration'
Read integer value 1
Setting value '1 {int}' for property 'DotNetFull_OSIntegrated'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNetFull_OSIntegrated] = 1 {int}
Property: [DotNetFull_Release] = 533320 {int}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX48\NDP48-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX48\NDP48-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX48\NDP48-Web.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThanEqualTo' on property 'DotNetFull_Release' and value '528040': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX48\NDP48-Web.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697211'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'http://fps104/solutions/solutions.application'.
```

It is showing publish succeeded in visual studio but it's not opening the URL link,  I'm using an FTP server from bluehost

Comment: This stack overflow question has some potential solutions here, although a different HRESULT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451496/urldownloadtocachefile-failed-with-hresult-2146697208

Comment: The thing is that it worked up until now, It stopped working after publishing my project locally and then  I tried publishing it again with FTP server